# Custom Membership Provider With EntityFramework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-membership

When I write my own custom membership provider with my own custom database and if I would like to put in "web form" "CreateUserWizard" control, I should use in my custom membership provider class - Entity Framework and implement all methods and properties from "MembershipProvider abstract class", am I right ?

Comment: What do you have currently?

Comment: MyCustomMemebership class and all methods from MembershipProvider abstract class but I am wondering am I supposed to use EntityFramework  to know these methods where in the columns the data should be writted. For example if I use "CreateUserWizard" control with custom membership provider this control should know automatically where to put data in tables in database.

Comment: @TheChampp are you working on an MVC app, and are you following code first approach?

Comment: I am working on Web Forms project and yes I am following code first.